# sending an email with python, html + css, reading an .txt file

Tags: python, html, email

I am trying to code something very simple. The idea is to read a .txt where a html code is written. Specifically it is a table with some css and style modifiers like:

```
 <td style=""background-color:red"" >-49,2%</td>
```

I can sucessfully read the content of the file and send the email. However, when the email is sent, no background style is applied. The rest of the table is created perfectly.
My code is something like:

```
fp = open(r"filepath", 'r',encoding='utf-8-sig')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read()) #Here I also tried with the argument 'html'
fp.close()
s.sendmail("email1", "email2",msg.as_string())
```

Is there any way I can also get the style applied? The email provider is gmail and I know it can work because if I try to use the 'msg' variable as a literal string, like:

```
msg= r"<table...> <td style=""background-color:red"" >-49,2%</td> </table>"
```

it sends the background format correctly. The issue must be of other sort.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I hope it helps,
The modifier.as_string() was the issue. Removing it on:

```
s.sendmail("email1", "email2",msg.as_string())
```

to

```
s.sendmail("email1", "email2",msg)
```

made it work.